# Javascript loaded but not working on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site where I'm using a popup plugin to play a video (Jetpack VideoPress).  The video keeps playing after the popup closes (and it also plays on page load before opening the popup if set to autoplay).  So I'm trying to fix that.  I have this external javascript from the plugin author that is meant to destroy the popup when closed.  122 is the popup id.

```
jQuery(document).on('spu.box_close',function(e,id) { 
  if( id == '122' ) {
    $('#spu-122').remove(); // this will destroy popup entirely
  }
});
```

I have enqueued the script from my functions.php (child theme) with this:

```
<?php
function jc_scripts_with_jquery() {
  wp_register_script( 'jc-script', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/jc-script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jc-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jc_scripts_with_jquery' );
```

But the script is not working.

Can anyone help?  Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Any console errors?  I need to refer to the docs.  Your use of passing in the id on the event handler looks odd to me

Comment: Thanks, Taplar, for the quick response.  No console errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: Put a console.log(id) in your event handler and see what it prints.  I have my doubts that the event handler is getting that value passed in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner.  The console says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()", but I double checked the URL path and it's all correct.

Comment: That may be another issue.  I don't see how that would affect your on() as it is.  So go ahead and try logging the id inside it

Comment: Here's the output:  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.zevo.io/home/wp_2bwykt/zevo.io/wp-content/themes/appthemechild/js/jc-script.js?ver=4.8.1'></script>

Comment: That's what console.log(id) prints?

Comment: Sorry, do I put it as:  console.log(122);

Comment: No, id is your variable.  I want to see what it's value is to see if it is, indeed, being passed in

Comment: I don't know of a variable here other than the spu-122 which is the popup box id from the plugin.

Comment: But the script is not being loaded like I thought.  Any idea why?

Comment: (I have to run, I'll be back in an hour.  Thanks so much for your help!)

Comment: I got it figured out.  I was outputting the wrong URL for some reason.  Taplar, you definitely helped me get to the bottom of it - thanks so much!  Have a great day!

Comment: Cool, but for future reference, `'spu-122'` isn't a variable.  That's a static string in your logic.  A variable is what `e`, `id` are that are passed into the function that will have various values.  Thus them being "variable".

Comment: Great, thanks, @Taplar!